# How to get the "Next Wallpaper" option after right click in Ubunutu 17.10?

Tags: window, shotwell

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and for wallpaper slideshow I am using Shotwell. But I want any script or any command by which I can add a “Next wallpaper” option after right click. Like in windows:

[image]

Comment: you can use the desktop/plasma build-in function: right-click on the desktop - `Configure Desktop` - then at Wallpaper Type choose Slideshow - then add the folders you want to use. finally Apply your changes. then if you right-click on the desktop you have a new context option `Next Wallpaper Image`

Comment: There is no option like configure desktop.  There is a option display setting but in there, no options are present to configure wallpaper setting.

Comment: sorry - i have not carefully enough read - you are on default ubuntu - my comment works on **K**ubuntu - its using the plasma desktop - thats 'fundamental' different to the GNOME Shell used in Ubuntu.